# explorer.exe memory could not be "written"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, crash

When I open Explorer after a few minutes I get an error message:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried to run `chkdsk /r /f`, `sfc /scannow` and CCleaner but the problem remains.
Also I have replaced the RAM but this is also not the solution

The same error occurs sometimes with `iexplore.exe` too. It's a Windows XP system.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Download and run [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) from a USB key (or CD/DVD).  Ensure your computer's RAM is functioning correctly.

Comment: The most common cause for this are shell add-ons (programs which add menu options to Explorer etc.). When they crash, it appears as an Explorer crash.